# Hibernate flush() affects transaction

Tags: java, hibernate, kotlin

I have the following Test-Case:

```kotlin
@Test
fun givenEntity_whenSaved_thenFound() {
    doInHibernate<Unit>(({ this.sessionFactory() }), { session ->
        val entity = getSampleEntity()

        session.persist(entity)
        session.flush()

        val entityFound = session.find(Entity::class.java, entity.id)

        session.refresh(entityFound )
        assertTrue(entityFound == entity)

        session.transaction.rollback()
    })
}
```

So I thought that the `session.flush()` would not affect my transaction so that it could rollback. However it does affect it, I get the following error:

```
Transaction not successfully started
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Transaction not successfully started
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:95)
    at org.hibernate.testing.transaction.TransactionUtil.doInHibernate(TransactionUtil.java:301)
    at data.base.EntityTest.givenEntity_whenSaved_thenFound(EntityTest.kt:20)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.testing.junit4.ExtendedFrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(ExtendedFrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.FailOnTimeout$CallableStatement.call(FailOnTimeout.java:288)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.FailOnTimeout$CallableStatement.call(FailOnTimeout.java:282)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

A workaround for this specific case would be this, but that still does not explain why the transaction is affected.

```kotlin
doInHibernate<Unit>(({ this.sessionFactory() }), { session ->
            val entity = getSampleEntity()

            session.persist(entity)
            assertTrue(session.contains(entity))

        })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I'm not sure about that, but I think my problem was that I had Autocommit enabled. So a possible fix would be:

```
hibernate.connection.autommit=false
```